# Persistence solutions for C++ (with a SQL database)?

Tags: c++, sql, database, frameworks, persistence

I'm wondering what kind of persistence solutions are there for C++ with a SQL database? In addition to doing things with custom SQL (and encapsulating the data access to DAOs or something similar), are there some other (more general) solutions?

Like some general libraries or frameworks (something like Hibernate & co for Java and .NET) or something else? (Something that I haven't even thought of can also be welcome to be suggested)

EDIT: Yep, I was searching more for an ORM solution or something similar to handle sql queries and the relationships between tables and objects than for the db engine itself. Thanks for all the answers anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for some ORM so that you don't have to bother with hand written SQL code.

There is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141/good-orm-for-c-solutions) that goes over ORM solutions for C++.

You also did not mention the type of application you are writing, if it is a desktop application, mobile application, server application.

Mobile: You are best off using SQLite as your database engine because it can be embedded and has a small footprint.

Desktop App: You should still consider using SQLite here, but you also have the option with most desktop applications to have an always on connection to the internet in which case you may want to provide a network server for this task.  I suggest using Apache + MySQL + PHP and using a lightweight ORM such as [Outlet ORM](http://www.outlet-orm.org/site/), and then using standard HTTP post calls to access your resources.

Server App: You have many more options here but I still suggest using Apache + MySQL + PHP + ORM because I find it is much easier to maintain this layer in a script language than in C++.

Comment: The link on ORM solutions for C++ is dead.

Answer (score 7):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is great: it's fast, stable, proven, and easy to use and integrate.

There is also [Metakit](http://www.equi4.com/metakit/) although the learning curve is a bit steep. But I've used it with success in a professional project.

Comment: You've forgot one important thing: SQLIte is free when used for any purposes.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Connector/C++ is a C++ implementation of JDBC 4.0

The reference customers who use MySQL Connector/C++ are:
- OpenOffice - MySQL Workbench

Learn more: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,221298

Answer (score 1):

SQLite + Hiberlite is a nice and promising project. though I hope to see it more actively developed. see http : // code.google.com/p/hiberlite/

Answer (score 0):

I use MYSQL or SQLite.

MYSQL: Provides a server based DB that your application must dynamically connect to.
SQLite:Provides an in memory or file base DB.

Using the in memory DB is useful for quick development as setting up and configuring a DB server just for a single project is a big task. But once you have a DB server up and running it's just as easy to sue that.

In memory DB is useful for holding small DB such as configuration etc.
While for larger data sets a DB server is probably more practical.

Download from here: http://dev.mysql.com/
Download from here: http://www.sqlite.org/