# How can I store data in C++ and make the data searchable?

Tags: c++, serialization, store, searchable

I'm working on an Address Book application in C++. I need to store the data and be able to retrieve it later. I know this requires serialization. I know how to serialize a simple map with a key and value.

I need to know how to store a lot of data, more than just one value. I will be storing: Name, Street Address, City, State, Zip Code, Personal E-mail, Work E-mail, Home Phone, Cellular Phone, Work Phone, Pager, Facebook, and Twitter. I would like to be able to search for any of these values in order to find a contact.

How can I go about storing all of this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I didn't really realize that I could go back and do that! Thanks, I guess that helps other people see which answers worked too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to go with something like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It will allow you to store your data in an SQL database that you can query for whatever information you want out of it.

Comment: Agreed. a relational DB like SQLite would let you efficiently search on anything you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need is a some form of small database to be distributed with your application. [See this SO question for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461580/persistence-solutions-for-c-with-a-sql-database) some possible choices (Including SQLite like Bart suggested).